# How to call an exported function?

Tags: typescript

My target is to call an exported function. I'm following the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and have this:

```
// Test.ts
export function test():void
{
    console.log("QWERTY");
}

// Main.ts
import {test} from "./third_party/Test"
window.onload = () => {
    test();
}

// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="build/library.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>

// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "build/library.js"
    }
}
```

Running the web page I have `ReferenceError: define is not defined at /mypath/build/library.js:1:2`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a module loader already loaded up.

[TypeScriptLang.org Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

> Modules import one another using a module loader. At runtime the module loader is responsible for locating and executing all dependencies of a module before executing it. Well-known modules loaders used in JavaScript are the CommonJS module loader for Node.js and require.js for Web applications.

[How to get started with RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Comment: Yes, RequireJS is that standard loader for AMD modules and works well with TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about different loaders. Anyway, I added `require.js`, my code compiles and I can even see a `console.log()` output from the `require([]...` function. But as soon as I add `import {test} from "./third_party/test/Test";` the function `require([]...` doesn't start. There're no errors or warnings, just an empty window.

Comment: @nikitablack That's a new question, you should make a new post for it.